# TextEdit can't save (or even autosave)

Tags: macos, error, mojave, textedit

I'm running Mojave as an update from Sierra— things were easier so far until last week when TextEdit started to do a number on me by not autosaving when it normally should, and worse still, not manually saving whatever changes I'd made. As Apple put it:

> The document "so-and-so.txt/.rtf(d)* could not be autosaved. Your changes will not be saved until the problem is resolved.

Uh, excuse me?? ***What*** problem do you mean? I just downloaded a few fonts prior to all this, so it couldn't have been anything *I* did. And I can't just duplicate this, because that won't save well either.

Is this some sorta glitch that popped back up? (I read it occurred quite often with MacOSX Mountain Lion)